# Dynamic widget/well panel in Shiny

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

I am trying to populate a dynamic number of widgets/well panels in shiny based on a user selection with the id "invar". The idea is to generate the widgets/well panels for each of the user selected variables which will then allow the user to define its probability distribution  and the probability distribution arguments. 
These variables after having their probability distributions defined will be used in a calculation. The following is the code :

```
library(shiny)
library(triangle)
library(readxl)
library(relaimpo)
library(data.table)
library(XLConnect)
library(xlsx)


ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Sensitivity & Uncertainty Analysis"),
  sidebarLayout(position = "left",
                sidebarPanel(
                  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.tabs1==1",
                                   tags$style(type='text/css', ".well { max-width: 20em; }"),
                                   # Tags:
                                   tags$head(
                                     tags$style(type="text/css", "select[multiple] { width: 100%; height:10em}"),
                                     tags$style(type="text/css", "select { width: 100%}"),
                                     tags$style(type="text/css", "input { width: 19em; max-width:100%}")
                                   ),

                                   # Select filetype:
                                   selectInput("readFunction", "Function to read data:", c(
                                     # Base R:
                                     "read.table",
                                     "read.csv",
                                     "read.csv2",
                                     "read.delim",
                                     "read.delim2",
                                     "readWorksheet",
                                     "read_excel",
                                     "read.xlsx"

                                   )),

                                   # Argument selecter:
                                   htmlOutput("ArgSelect"),

                                   # Argument field:
                                   htmlOutput("ArgText"),

                                   # Upload data:
                                   fileInput("file", "Upload data-file:"),

                                   # Variable selection:
                                   htmlOutput("varselect"),

                                   br(),

                                   uiOutput("invar"),
                                   br(),
                                   uiOutput("outvar"),

                                   textInput("name","Dataset name:","Data")),


                  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.tabs1==2",
                                   sliderInput("sampleSize","Please Select Sample Size:",min = 0,max = 5000,value = 1000,step = 100),

                                   uiOutput("distinvar"))


                ),
                mainPanel(
                  tabsetPanel(id="tabs1",
                              tabPanel("Data File",value = 1,tableOutput("table")),
                              tabPanel("Monte Carlo",value=2,plotOutput("Histogram"))
                  )
                )

  ))



server<-function(input, output) {
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2)

  ### Argument names:
  ArgNames <- reactive({
    Names <- names(formals(input$readFunction)[-1])
    Names <- Names[Names!="..."]
    return(Names)
  })

  # Argument selector:
  output$ArgSelect <- renderUI({
    if (length(ArgNames())==0) return(NULL)

    selectInput("arg","Argument:",ArgNames())
  })

  ## Arg text field:
  output$ArgText <- renderUI({
    fun__arg <- paste0(input$readFunction,"__",input$arg)

    if (is.null(input$arg)) return(NULL)

    Defaults <- formals(input$readFunction)

    if (is.null(input[[fun__arg]]))
    {
      textInput(fun__arg, label = "Enter value:", value = deparse(Defaults[[input$arg]])) 
    } else {
      textInput(fun__arg, label = "Enter value:", value = input[[fun__arg]]) 
    }
  })


  ### Data import:
  Dataset <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$file)) {
      # User has not uploaded a file yet
      return(data.frame())
    }

    args <- grep(paste0("^",input$readFunction,"__"), names(input), value = TRUE)

    argList <- list()
    for (i in seq_along(args))
    {
      argList[[i]] <- eval(parse(text=input[[args[i]]]))
    }
    names(argList) <- gsub(paste0("^",input$readFunction,"__"),"",args)

    argList <- argList[names(argList) %in% ArgNames()]

    Dataset <- as.data.frame(do.call(input$readFunction,c(list(input$file$datapath),argList)))
    return(Dataset)
  })

  # Select variables:
  output$varselect <- renderUI({

    if (identical(Dataset(), '') || identical(Dataset(),data.frame())) return(NULL)

    # Variable selection:    
    selectInput("vars", "Variables to use:",
                names(Dataset()), names(Dataset()), multiple =TRUE)            
  })

  # Show table:
  output$table <- renderTable({

    if (is.null(input$vars) || length(input$vars)==0) return(NULL)

    return(Dataset()[,input$vars,drop=FALSE])
  })

  #################################################################################

  varnames<-reactive({
    names(input$readFunction)
  })

  output$invar<-renderUI({
    selectizeInput('invar',"Select Regression Input Variables", choices = names(Dataset()), multiple = TRUE)
  })

  output$outvar<-renderUI({
    selectizeInput('outvar',"Select Regression Output Variable", choices = names(Dataset()), multiple = TRUE)

  })


  d.f<-Dataset


    output$distinvar<-renderUI({
      numvar<- length(input$invar())
      lapply(1:numvar, function(i) {
        selectInput("distinvar","Please Select Probability Distribution of Input Variable:",
                    choices = c("Normal","Uniform","Triangular"))
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.distinvar=='Normal'",
                         textInput("invarpdfmean","Please Select Input Variable Mean:",0.25),
                         textInput("invarpdfsd","Please Select Input Variable Standard Deviation", 0.02))
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.distinvar=='Uniform'",
                         textInput("invarpdfmin","Please Select Minimum Input Variable Value:",0.18),
                         textInput("invarpdfmax","Please Select Maximum Input Variable Value", 0.3))
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.distinvar=='Triangular'",
                         textInput("invarpdfmin","Please Select Minimum Input Variable Value:",0.18),
                         textInput("invarpdfmax","Please Select Maximum Input Variable Value:", 0.3))
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.distinvar=='Log Normal'",
                         textInput("invarpdfmeanlog","Please Select Mean Log of Input Variable:",0.18),
                         textInput("invarpdfsdlog","Please Select Standard Deviation Log of Input Variable:", 0.3))
      })



      output$MonteCarlo <- renderPlot({
        set.seed(1)


        n <- input$sampleSize




        if(distinvar=="Normal"){

          invarpdfVec <- rnorm(n,mean = as.numeric(input$invarpdfmean),sd= as.numeric(input$invarpdfsd))
        }
        if(distinvar=="Uniform"){

          invarpdfVec <- runif(n,min = as.numeric(input$invarpdfmin),max = as.numeric(input$invarpdfmax))
        }
        if(distinvar=="Triangular"){

          invarpdfVec <- rltriangle(n,a = as.numeric(input$invarpdfmin),b = as.numeric(input$invarpdfmax))
        }
        if(distinvar=="Log Normal"){

          invarpdfVec <- rlnorm(n,meanlog = as.numeric(input$invarpdfmeanlog),sdlog = as.numeric(input$invarpdfsdlog))
        }




        for (n in 1:input$sampleSize){
          h<- (0.1*distinvar+100)
        }


        hist(h)

      })})
  }







shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Is my approach correct, what am I not understanding/doing wrong as I am not able to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
I have added the reproducible example. input$invar is a user selected variable which allows the user to select a number of variables from a list on uploaded data.

Comment: first of all You did not give any sufficient information about `input$invar`, and on a first look Your `output$distinvar` does not make any sense. You cannot render `selectInput` & `textInput` together under one `renderUI`! Second thing in Your case i would use `if...else...` statement rather then `conditionalPanel`. Please provide reproducible example

Comment: @Malvina_a can you please elaborate on why the 'output$distvar' does not make any sense. I will look into 'selectInput ' and 'text Input'.

Comment: You cannot render two widgets under one `renderUI` that is `output$distvar`. I am going to have a look at Your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to play a bit with Your code and here is the result with `mtcars` dataset:

```
library(shiny)

ui= fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput(inputId= "invar", label= "invar", 
                     choices= names(mtcars), 
                     selected= names(mtcars)[1],
                     multiple=T),
      uiOutput("distinvar"),
      uiOutput("distinvar2")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("tab")
    )
  ))


server= function(input, output,session) {

  sorted <-  reactive({
    data <- mtcars[ ,c(input$invar)]
    #print(input$invar)
    data})

  output$distinvar<-renderUI({
    numvar<- length(input$invar) # not input$ivar()!
    #print(numvar)
    lapply(1:numvar, function(i) {
      selectInput(inputId=paste0("distinvar",input$invar[i]),paste0("Please Select Probability Distribution of ", input$invar[i]),
                  choices = c("Normal","Uniform","Triangular"))})})

  output$distinvar2<-renderUI({
    numvar<- length(input$invar) # not input$ivar()!
    lapply(1:numvar, function(i) {
      if(eval(parse(text=paste0("input$",paste0("distinvar",input$invar[i])))) == "Normal"){
       textInput(paste0("invarpdfmean",input$invar[i]),"Please Select Input Variable Mean:",0.25)
      }
      else if(eval(parse(text=paste0("input$",paste0("distinvar",input$invar[i])))) == "Uniform"){
        textInput(paste0("invarpdfmin",input$invar[i]),"Please Select Minimum Input Variable Value:",0.18)
      }
      else{
        textInput(paste0("invarpdfmin",input$invar[i]),"Please Select Minimum Input Variable Value:",0.18),
      }
  })})


  output$tab= renderTable(sorted())



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This code still has to be improved by one more function with extra `textInput` for `max` values!

Comment: thanks for the reply and explaining the mistakes. Is there anyway to create a layout similar to this here [https://uasnap.shinyapps.io/RV_distributionsV4/]. I would like to have the conditionals under each distribution

Comment: sorry I have yet to figure out how to format. this is the link: https://uasnap.shinyapps.io/RV_distributionsV4/